# How to split lists in python?

Tags: python, list, split

I have some lists as follows:

```
['apple,orange,cherry', 'tomato,potato,cucumber', 'pear,grape, kiwi']
['fish,chicken,beef', 'milk,juice,tea', 'Facebook,twitter,instagram']
...
```

I want to split the strings in the lists like this:

```
[['apple', 'orange', 'cherry'], [...], [...]]
...
```

I have tried `split`, but it didn't work.

Comment: Please expand on *"didn't work"*. Give a [mcve]. Did you try to `.split` the list and get an `AttributeError`, by any chance?

Comment: `[s.split(',') for s in l]`

Answer (score 7):

You probably just need to pass a split character (i.e. `,`) in to `split`.  By default, it only splits on whitespace.

```
a = ['apple,orange,cherry', 'tomato,potato,cucumber', 'pear,grape, kiwi']
b = [s.split(',') for s in a]
```

Comment: oh, why there is always a [' '] at the end of each list? I mean, an empty list.

Comment: @J.Q I'm not sure what you mean.  Do your strings start or end with a comma?  Or is there an empty string in your list?  Your strings must be different from the examples you provided.